# after login google plus button not working

Tags: php

I have use following code for showing google plus but after signing it become warning sign and count always show 0

script for google plus

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

for display button

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="http://182.73.117.21/development/pixmettle/"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">gapi.plusone.go();</script>
```

Comment: What does your console tell you?